# What do the various IP addresses mean?

Tags: networking, ip, nat

When I visit a website (e.g. whatismyip.com) it states that my IP address is `13.151.xxx.xxx`. However, when I run `ipconfig`, my IP address is `192.168.0.xx` for IPv4 and my DNS adress is `202.xx.xxx.xx`.

Why is there a difference? Also, how can I find the first IP address through the command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Linux if you type `ifconfig` it shows your system IP address. And in the browser if you enter www.ipaddress.com it shows your Internet connection IP address.

In your case,

- `192.168.0.x` --> System IP address
- `13.151.xxx.xxx.` --->Internet connection.

Always the IP address shown in the ifconfig is the first IP address

Comment: If I have a web server running from 192.168.0.x, how do I access it from the outside?

Comment: You can grant access to internal systems using [Port Forwarding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding). With Port Forwarding your router would redirect incoming connections for TCP port 80 to port 80 on your internal machine.

Answer (score 3):

Your computer is behind a router that is using [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) to share a single connection to the Internet. I would setup an account with dyndns.com and install the client on your computer. Once that is done you should always be able to find the IP of your router with a dns query for "yourname".dyndns.com. Some routers also have dynamic dns clients built in.

Comment: if someone ask me what is my IP, which one should I answer?

Comment: Your external if they're not in your home. Your internal if you're connected to the same network